# angular2 routing not working when you deployed dist folder onto tomcat server

Tags: angular, tomcat, angular2-routing, angular-cli

I generated **dist** folder in my project **prj-routing-final**  with **angular-cli** with command  `ng-build --prod --aot`  and deployed on to tomcat server. i was able to navigate to all routes `http://localhost:8081/dist/` and view them without reloading. Once if i navigate to `http://localhost:8081/dist/recipes/0`  and  reload the page this error coming up

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found  
Type Status Report
Message /dist/recipes/0
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Apache Tomcat/8.5.14
```

I am not getting any errors if i serve with `ng serve`. i was able navigate to all routes, reload the pages, move back and forth.

I also tried serving **dist** with  **Http-server** available in https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server   getting same kind of error after reloading 
`No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8080/recipes/0` 
[GitHub repo of my project](https://github.com/venkatakrishna874/angular4)

Please kindly help me.

Comment: You server is not configured to work with `html5Mode`. This may give you an idea on how to proceed https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: Thank you for your response @LenilsondeCastro  , is anything I need to add my script files to enable `html5Mode` or by default it's enabled.

Comment: Something like this https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to configure your web server to redirect all unknown (404) requests to index.html, which will allow the Angular application to then route your user to the desired route/view.

Comment: Thank you @Brocco   for your quick  response. I have no idea how to redirect tomcat server to index.html for all unknown request. Can you please guide me.