# Spring Cloud Gatway with Angular Routing

Tags: angular, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a Spring Cloud Gatway that routes to an Angular application which is hosted on a Tomcat server under localhost:9092/admin. This is my gateway configuration

```
server:
  port: 9091
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: adminui
        uri: http://localhost:9092
        predicates:
        - Path=/admin/**
```

This is working well. Now I started using Angular routing and added sub-urls like

```
/admin/users
```

This is working well until I hit refresh in the browser, or when I try navigating directly to the given url. Then I get a

```
404-NotFound
```

from the gateway, since this resource cannot be found in the Tomcat folder where the Angular "dist" is being hosted.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was a general problem, hosting such SPA pages on Tomcat. So it´s the same issue than here
[angular2 routing not working when you deployed dist folder onto tomcat server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44832705/angular2-routing-not-working-when-you-deployed-dist-folder-onto-tomcat-server)

The solution was to tell the gateway to route requests to any of the Angular routes to the index.html in Tomcat

```
  routes:
  - id: adminuisub
    uri: http://localhost:9092
    predicates:
    - Path=/admin/users/**
    filters:
    - SetPath=/admin/index.html
```